# In dijit.form.select it is not selecting appropriate one

Tags: dijit.form

I want to fix the element from the drop down by default using `dijit.form.select`. It is loading the different value by default and I want to replace it.

I am able to select other options expect the required one.

You can find my code below:

```
    function loadHoldQueueNames(data)
        {
//              statusUpdate("Load Hold Queue Names...");

            var holdQueuesData = new Array();
            holdQueuesData[0] = {id : "", label : "Hold Queue!"};
            for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) holdQueuesData[i+1] =  {id : data.data[i], label : data.data[i]};
            holdQueuesStore = new Memory({data: holdQueuesData});
            var os = new ObjectStore({ objectStore: holdQueuesStore });

            omgmeatHoldQueueSelect = new dijit.form.Select({
                name: "omgmeatHoldQueueSelect",
                store: omgmeatHoldQueueSelectValue,
                disabled: !userProfile.allowHoldQueue,
                value : omgmeatHoldQueueSelectValue
            }, "omgmeatHoldQueueSelect");
            omgmeatHoldQueueSelect.startup();
            style.set("omgmeatHoldQueueSelect", {width: "200px"});
            dojo.connect(omgmeatHoldQueueSelect, "onChange", updateNextOrderButton);

        };
```

Can any one help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In code it had return to sort by label and the particular element is disabled so it is not selecting once after I had added sortbylabel id as false shown below and then it is working fine.

```
new dijit.form.Select({
            name: "omgmeatHoldQueueSelect",
            store: omgmeatHoldQueueSelectValue,
            disabled: !userProfile.allowHoldQueue,
            sortbylabel:false,
            value : omgmeatHoldQueueSelectValue
        }, "omgmeatHoldQueueSelect");
```

The problem is DOJO migration that I had done will sort the label by default we need to apply the label to false then it will work fine.